# Flutter: I am getting an outdated message when trying to launch

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication

Hey can someone help me I followed a tutorial from about 2 years ago to make a login/auth page that links with firebase. I tried to run the app at the end and it opens launch.json and asks for a configuration. Here is the code it wants me to add a config to.

```
"version": "0.2.0", "configurations": [

    {
        "name": "Flutter",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "dart"
    }
]
}
```

Here is the link to the tutorial github.  Is there any way I can fix it to run now? https://github.com/tattwei46/flutter_login_demo

Answer (score 0):

`launch.json` is a VSCode file that stores different build methods for your workspace. It's not really related to your flutter project setup. Allow VSCode to add the config to the file and it should work fine. If launching using VSCode shortcuts is not necessary, you can just do `flutter run`.

You can read more about this file [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging). This doc uses a different language as an example, however, this doesn't matter as the file is for VSCode, not flutter/dart.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to create new **flutter project** then  copy flutter_login_demo lib into the new flutter project lib with pakages in yaml and images if icluded. its better becuase you may get extra errors like android X error .